# How to programmatically hide cells of a DataGrid in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

Would there be any way to hide/collapse specific dataGrid cells in code-behind? Since my datatable columns are created at run-time, I'm unable to specify properties (in XAML) to properly setup these datatriggers, templateselectors, etc. 
I am, however, able to locate the exact cells I want to collapse by looping through the datatable to add the row/column indexes to a List (below).

I know this is unorthodox, but I've been reading threads for weeks trying to solve this and nothing has gotten me there. This seems like would be the simplest solution (if possible).

```
private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> GetCellsToHide(DataTable pivotTable)
{
    var noCellValueList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
    foreach (DataRow row in pivotTable.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in pivotTable.Columns)
        {
            if (row[col].ToString() == "HideMe")
            {
                int rowIndex = pivotTable.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                int colIndex = pivotTable.Columns.IndexOf(col);

                noCellValueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(rowIndex, colIndex));

            }
        }
    }

    return noCellValueList;
}
```

---

Edit: datatemplate & converter information

I'm currently building the datagrid by autogeneratingcolumns. I know the names of all other columns so I can narrow down to the dynamically generated ones. My dynamic columns are DataTemplate5, for instance (simplified version below):

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Name")
        e.Column.Header = "File Name";

    else
    {
        string origHeader = e.Column.Header.ToString();

        DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn    //create new template column
        {
             Header = origHeader,
             CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["DataTemplate5"]

        }; 

        e.Column = templateColumn; // Replace the auto-generated column with the templateColumn.    
    }
}
```

But since I don't have the property (column) names to bind to, I haven't been able to bind it correctly. Here's my latest attempt at hiding cells via the datatemplate & ivalueconverter:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate5">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <local:StringToVisibilityConvertor x:Key="VisibilityConvertor" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}">
        <Button Name="Button1" Click="ButtonClick">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style  TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the converter:

```
public class StringToVisibilityConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString() != "HideMe")
            return Visibility.Visible;
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Comment: Just trying to be clear - you're talking about hiding whole columns, right? Your question says that, but then you're explanation seems to be talking about individual cells. If you are talking cells, what are you hoping will happen when a cell is hidden?  
If you are talking about columns, have you tried just setting the DataColumn's visibility to Collapsed?

Comment: Apologies I've edited the title. I mean to hide specific cells, not entire columns.

Comment: My datatable is comprised of tons of columns of links. My datagrid displays them as buttons which open the links. Even though lots of cells have null values, they're displayed as buttons nonetheless and are a bad representation of the data. I need those cells to be blank and only display buttons in cells that have links to open.

Comment: Really need to see your code for building the DataGrid I think - what sort of Columns are you using? It sounds like DataTemplate columns, but then what's in your template definition?

Comment: Thanks Ian, added more information above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the dynamic columns, I was not able to get my bindings to work. In the end, I stumbled upon a great article by Paul Stovell on how to create the grid using the column index as the binding path. After doing this, I created a datatemplate for all columns and hid the cell with datatrigger:

http://paulstovell.com/blog/dynamic-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Must admit, I've never gone this far in tweaking the auto-generation of columns - I rarely use auto-generated columns, although I guess you have to as you don't know the columns until run time.

If it were me, I'd tweak the template thus:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate5">
    <Button Name="Button1" Click="ButtonClick" Background="Orange" Content="{Binding ???}" >
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ???}" Value="HideMe">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Saves the need for the converter. Question now though is what to put for the ???. Try nothing - ie just {Binding}.

You may also need to add a little to your code behind:

```
                 DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn    //create new template column
                 {
                     Header = origHeader,
                     CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["DataTemplate5"],
                     SortMemberPath = e.Column.SortMemberPath
                 };
```

Actually, try that first - it may be enough, along with some debugging in your value converter.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I did follow your advice and got rid of the converter. Still wasn't able to get the bindings working, unfortunately. I posted an answer that got me what I needed, although this method does have it's drawbacks.

Comment: Great that you got it worked out - guess you can mark your answer as the answer, unless you care to elaborate a bit more for future reference.

Comment: Absolutely. I marked answer (above) and provided the article hyperlink.

Comment: meant to add... what I essentially did was take my datatable and convert it into an observablecollection. What took care of the big question mark -bindings- were his "CustomBoundColumn" that set the bindings in code-behind. I still only partially understand his code for this, or else I'd elaborate more, but would have never figured it out on my own and would point anybody interested to the website!

Comment: Thanks for heads up, ticked it.